# JPA: Map a db column to two fields in an entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have a legacy system where there is a database column, ITEM varchar2(15) and I want to map the table to a jpa entity, and 
I would like split the column, ITEM, to an entity field itemPrefix which will contain first 8 characters and itemSuffix which contain the last 7 characters, what is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do such thing in Hibernate. I suggest to map both columns and create a getter and setter as you could see below (In addition of those you already have to create):

```
private String itemPrefix ;
private String itemSuffix ;
```

and a get/set method like:

```
 public String getItemPrefixPostFix(){
        return this.itemPrefix + this.itemSuffix ;
    }
```

Setter would look something like

```
public void setItemPrefixPostFix(String str) {

   this.itemPrefix = str.substring(0, 8);;
   this.itemSuffix = str.substring(8, str.length();
}
```